# Mysql Call function inside another function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have two functions. set_credit_values and do_credit. I will call the second one from inside first one. Then it is getting error `1 errors were found during analysis.Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 983)`, `#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function`. My code is as follows

```
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS do_credit;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION do_credit (ltp_id int, cr_count tinyint, cr_on tinyint, next_cr date, cr_period tinyint) 
            RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                INSERT IGNORE INTO aaa_test(aaa_ltp_id, aaa_cr_count, aaa_cr_on, aaa_next_cr, aaa_cr_period) VALUES 
                 (ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period);
                RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();

            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;   

            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_credit_values;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION set_credit_values (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int, elp_date date) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                DECLARE ltp_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE cr_count tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE cr_on tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE next_cr DATE DEFAULT NULL;
                DECLARE cr_period tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;

                DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

                DEClARE cur_set_credit CURSOR FOR                     
                SELECT lpb_fk_leave_type, lpb_cr_count, lpb_cr_on, lpb_next_cr,  lpb_cr_period FROM erp_leave_policy_body
                WHERE lpb_fk_leave_policy = lpc_id;

                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

                OPEN cur_set_credit;

                    get_cr: LOOP

                        FETCH cur_set_credit INTO ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period;

                        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                        LEAVE get_cr;
                        END IF;

                        SELECT do_credit(ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period) FROM DUAL;


                    END LOOP get_cr;

                CLOSE cur_set_credit;

                RETURN 1;
            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;
```

It is working me successfully if I write the insert query inside set_credit_values function without calling the do_credit function as follows

```
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_credit_values;

            DELIMITER $$;
            CREATE FUNCTION set_credit_values (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int, elp_date date) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN

                DECLARE ltp_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE cr_count tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE cr_on tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE next_cr DATE DEFAULT NULL;
                DECLARE cr_period tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;

                DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

                DEClARE cur_set_credit CURSOR FOR                     
                SELECT lpb_fk_leave_type, lpb_cr_count, lpb_cr_on, lpb_next_cr,  lpb_cr_period FROM erp_leave_policy_body
                WHERE lpb_fk_leave_policy = lpc_id;

                DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

                OPEN cur_set_credit;

                    get_cr: LOOP

                        FETCH cur_set_credit INTO ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period;

                        IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                        LEAVE get_cr;
                        END IF;

                        INSERT IGNORE INTO aaa_test(aaa_ltp_id, aaa_cr_count, aaa_cr_on, aaa_next_cr, aaa_cr_period) VALUES 
                 (ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period);


                    END LOOP get_cr;

                CLOSE cur_set_credit;

                RETURN 1;
            END $$;
            DELIMITER ;
```

But I need it to be do in do_credit function because I need to do some other queries with this. So please anybody help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in below code,kindly `DECLARE one VARIABLE` and after calling function get returned value in that variable using `INTO` keyword.
Hope this will helps you.

```
 DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS do_credit;

                DELIMITER $$;
                CREATE FUNCTION do_credit (ltp_id int, cr_count tinyint, cr_on tinyint, next_cr date, cr_period tinyint) 
                RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
                BEGIN

                    INSERT IGNORE INTO aaa_test(aaa_ltp_id, aaa_cr_count, aaa_cr_on, aaa_next_cr, aaa_cr_period) VALUES 
                     (ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period);
                    RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();

                END $$;
                DELIMITER ;   

                DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_credit_values;

                DELIMITER $$;
                CREATE FUNCTION set_credit_values (emp_id bigint, lpc_id int, elp_date date) RETURNS boolean DETERMINISTIC
                BEGIN

                    DECLARE ltp_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE var_id INT(11) DEFAULT 0; <--Declare this variable
                    DECLARE cr_count tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE cr_on tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
                    DECLARE next_cr DATE DEFAULT NULL;
                    DECLARE cr_period tinyint(4) DEFAULT 0;

                    DECLARE v_finished INT(11) DEFAULT 0;

                    DEClARE cur_set_credit CURSOR FOR                     
                    SELECT lpb_fk_leave_type, lpb_cr_count, lpb_cr_on, lpb_next_cr,  lpb_cr_period FROM erp_leave_policy_body
                    WHERE lpb_fk_leave_policy = lpc_id;

                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

                    OPEN cur_set_credit;

                        get_cr: LOOP

                            FETCH cur_set_credit INTO ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period;

                            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                            LEAVE get_cr;
                            END IF;

                            SELECT do_credit(ltp_id, cr_count, cr_on, next_cr, cr_period) into var_id FROM DUAL; <--get return value in declared variable>


                        END LOOP get_cr;

                    CLOSE cur_set_credit;

                    RETURN 1;
                END $$;
                DELIMITER ;
```